# grep command to search in subdirectories

Tags: unix, grep

I have a directory named lists, and have several subdirectories in this named as lists-01, lists-02 and so on.
In every subdirectory, I have a sript called checklist.
I want to use grep command to search for "margin" in each script "checklist", and want to know the particular checklist scripts which contain the word "margin".
I tried using

```
 grep "margin" list*/checklist
```

but, this is not giving any result.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `--include` to select just the files you want:

```
grep -Rl --include='*checklist' "margin" .
```

I am trying to figure out how to include `list-0*/` directories, still couldn't find a way.

---

Note also that your attempt was quite accurate. You only need to add `-R` for recursive:

```
grep -R "margin" list-[0-9]*/checklist
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find lists -name checklist -type f -exec grep -H margin {} \;
```

That says... find, starting in the directory called `lists`, and all directories below, all files called `checklist` and look in them for the word `margin` printing the filename if it is in there.

If you have a modern `find,` you can replace the `\;` with `+` to allow each `find` to search more than one file and make your query more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It will search all the files named checklist recursively and then run grep command on those files to find word "margin". -l option will give you only file name and option -w is used for exact match.

```
find ~/list -type f -name checklist -exec grep -lw "margin" {} +
```